# STL Container move selected elements

Tags: c++, stl

How to select elements with certain value from STL container and move them at the end of that container?

Comment: Please include your code and how it is failing.

Comment: Be specific. Which container?

Comment: I did not specified which container because I want to hear what container is best for that. But Vector or List could be my choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering you made a comment about wanting to use std::vector, I'd suggest using std::partition or std::stable_partition, i.e.:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int init_values[] = {1, 1, 7, 3, 19, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10, 5, 1};
    std::vector<int> values(
        init_values,
        init_values + sizeof(init_values) / sizeof(int)
    );

    std::stable_partition(
        values.begin(), values.end(),
        std::bind1st(std::not_equal_to<int>(), 5)
    );

    std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This code will move all elements of the vector that are equal to 5 to the end of the vector, keeping the relative order of the remaining elements in tact.

Comment: @userbb: The Standard Library has several "ordering" [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) with _different uses and performance_ (`std::partition`, `std::stable_partition`, `std::nth_element`, `std::partial_sort`, `std::stable_sort`, `std::sort`).

Answer (score 5):

You could try using `std::partition` with a predicate that returns `true` for elements *not equal* to the target value. If you need to to preserve the relative order of the elements there is also `std::stable_partition`.